# Fluent Nhibernate Mapping with Column

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Hi i am stuck with one problem while dealing with fluent nhibernate.

My user entity is below

> public class UserEntity
>       {
>           public virtual int Userid { get; set; }
>           public virtual CompanyEntity CompanyId { get; set; }
>           public virtual string Name { get; set; }
>           public virtual string Email { get; set; }
>           public virtual string Username { get; set; }
>           public virtual string Password { get; set;}
>           public virtual decimal MinLimit { get; set;}
>           public virtual decimal MaxLimit { get; set;}
>           public virtual DateTime Birthdate { get; set;}
>           public virtual RoleEntity Roleid { get; set; }
>          public virtual int CreatedBy { get; set;}
>           public virtual DateTime CreatedDate { get; set;}
>           public virtual bool Active { get; set;}
>       }
>   }

and mapping class is as below

> public class UserMap : ClassMap
>           {
>               public UserMap()
>               {
>                   Id(x => x.Userid);
>                   References(x => x.CompanyId).Column("CompanyId").Cascade.All();
>                   Map(x => x.Name);
>                   Map(x => x.Email);
>                   Map(x => x.Username);
>                   Map(x => x.Password);
>                   Map(x => x.MinLimit);
>                   Map(x => x.MaxLimit);
>                   Map(x => x.Birthdate);
>                   References(x => x.Roleid).Column("Roleid").Cascade.All();
>                   Map(x => x.CreatedBy);
>                   Map(x => x.CreatedDate);
>                   Map(x => x.Active);
>                   Table("tblUsers");
>               }
>           }

Now when ever i am trying to execute my program it gives me error like.

> Could not determine type for: ProductPO.Models.Entites.UserEntity, ProductPO, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(CreatedBy)

My helper class is as below

> private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

```
    private static ISessionFactory sessionFactory  
    {  
        get  
        {  
            if (_sessionFactory == null)  
            {  
                initialisationFactory();  
            }  

            return _sessionFactory;  
        }  

    }  
    private static void initialisationFactory()  
    {  
        try  
        {  

            _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()  
                            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ConnectionString(@"Server=10.10.10.10;Database=Product;uid=sa;pwd=12345;Trusted_Connection=false;").ShowSql())    
                            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<CompanyEntity>().ExportTo("d:\\"))  
                            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ModuleEntity>().ExportTo("d:\\"))    
                            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<RoleEntity>().ExportTo("d:\\"))  
                            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<UserEntity>().ExportTo("d:\\"))  
                            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg))  
                            .BuildSessionFactory();  
        }  
        catch (Exception e)  
        {  

            throw;  
        } 
    }  
    public static ISession OpenSession()  
    {  
        return sessionFactory.OpenSession();  
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will fix the problem but your mapping class should pass the model type into the base class like this:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<UserEntity>
```

Also does the CreatedBy column exist in the underlying table?

Could you post the inner exception if there is one....

Comment: I figured it out. Actually i had a relationship of users table with role table and forgot to put it in entity class... but thx for your post. i am highly obliged.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that the assembly that is set your UserEntity **is not the same** as it is defined your UserMap.

### Configure your mappings:

```
Fluently.Configure() 
    .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ConnectionString("{OMITED}").ShowSql()) 
    .Mappings(m => {
        AddFromAssemblyOf<UserMap>()
    })  
    .ExposeConfiguration( c => 
        new SchemaExport(c)
        .Execute(false, true, false) 
    )
```

No need to add one to one mapping. This way the Fluent NHibernate search the entire assemblie classes that inherit from ClassMap

Comment: I figured it out. Actually i had a relationship of users table with role table and forgot to put it in entity class... but thx for your post. i am highly obliged.